# How to use session in classic asp for passing value to html?

Tags: session, asp-classic

I m new to classic asp, in my header page, need to pass variable using session.

My session name is, `session("falias")=""`

and here is my html,

```
    <li class="user" >

<span class="res" >Michael</span></li>
```

I need to show any other name instead of this name Michael, so how to do with using session.

I don't even how to write a code, please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span class="res" ><%=session("falias") %></span></li>
```

Comment: try losing the semi colon - (assuming you're using VBS and not JS)

Comment: So you need to put it in an img  tag - eg `<img src="<%=session("fpictureMedium") %>" />` or use css to make it the background of a `<div>`.  Google is your friend

Comment: You still need to use client side code which tells the browser that it's an image or it will just appear as text

Comment: Your session variable is just a bit of text.  Your browser needs to interpret that as the location of an image.  `<img src="<%=session("fpictureMedium") %>" />` will appear as `<img src="img/happy-family-on-the-grassMedium.jpg" />` in your source code once the server has rendered your page

Comment: Alternatively, you could have an entire image tag as your session variable eg `session("fpictureMedium") = "<img src=""img/happy-family-on-the-grassMedium.jpg"" />"` Note the double double quotes.

Comment: Would have been better if you provided some explanation as to what `<%= %>` does. For those not familiar the `<% %>` identifies that the contained statement is run server-side against the ASP ISAPI extension. The `=` is a shorthand version of the method `Response.Write()` which outputs strings to the client, the above statement could also be written as `<% Response.Write Session("falias") %>`.

Comment: Have the OP's comments been removed from this answer?  Looks like you're talking to yourself, @John!

Comment: @Paul  Yes, they have.  He was asking how to define an image in a session object, because putting `<%=session("fpictureMedium") %>` inside a span tag didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=Session("falias")%>
```

or

```
<% Response.Write Session("falias") %>
```

Comment: Again no [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715386/how-to-use-session-in-classic-asp-for-passing-value-to-html#comment47617978_29716231)